# How to use async functions in StreamExt::filter

Tags: asynchronous, rust

I have a `Stream` of values and I want to `filter` it by some predicate. But what if the predicate itself is an `async` function?

```
#[async_std::test]
async fn test() {
    use async_std::prelude::*;
    use async_std::stream;

    let mut s = stream::from_iter(vec![1u8, 2, 3, 4]);

    let mut s = s.filter(|x| check_if_in_db(x).await); // error: this is not `async`

    assert_eq!(s.next().await, Some(1));
    assert_eq!(s.next().await, Some(2));
    assert_eq!(s.next().await, None);
}

async fn check_if_in_db(x: &u8) -> bool {
    x <= &2
}
```

I struggle with making `filter` predicate returning `bool` at the same time as being `async`.

Comment: Maybe using `flat_map()` an return a `stream::empty()` or `stream::once()` instead of `false` and `true`?

Comment: What about `s.filter(|x| async { check_if_in_db(x).await })`?

Comment: I guess yes : https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=099a664471b84446a77de05a960e05d2 ( run test )